Bug in JDK 9+ in Linux: StackOverflowError in Graphics
Our AWT-based Java app is giving a StackOverflowError on Ubuntu Linux JDKs 11 to 23 frequently (but thread-stochastically). See 3 example stack traces below. Suggestions or commiseration? We've mitigated it partly by diverting the components' validate() to a separate thread so that the AWT EventQueue doesn't hang. We suspect a bug in Java itself. (Our app began in 1997, has >>200K lines, and will not be converted to Swing. Works fine JDKs 8 to 23 macOS & Windows & JDK 8 in Linux.)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.View.getContainer(View.java:1014)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateMetrics(WrappedPlainView.java:442)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.getPreferredSpan(WrappedPlainView.java:540)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.getPreferredSpan(BasicTextUI.java:1454)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTextUI.java:950)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTextAreaUI.java:121)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1734)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTextArea.getPreferredSize(JTextArea.java:623)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:799)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1541)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1530)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1725)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1660)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11.XTextAreaPeer.setFont(XTextAreaPeer.java:392)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.validate(Component.java:2988)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1660)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11.XTextAreaPeer.setFont(XTextAreaPeer.java:392)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.validate(Component.java:2988)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1660)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11.XTextAreaPeer.setFont(XTextAreaPeer.java:392)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.validate(Component.java:2988)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1743)

etc....
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.getNode(HashMap.java:576)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:564)
    at java.desktop/sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFRCFromCache(SwingUtilities2.java:1281)
    at java.desktop/sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFRCProperty(SwingUtilities2.java:1255)
    at java.desktop/sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1238)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1700)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateMetrics(WrappedPlainView.java:444)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.getPreferredSpan(WrappedPlainView.java:540)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.getPreferredSpan(BasicTextUI.java:1454)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTextUI.java:950)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTextAreaUI.java:121)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1734)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTextArea.getPreferredSize(JTextArea.java:623)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:799)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1541)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1530)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1725)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1660)

and then the infinite loop as above....
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder.getBorderInsets(AbstractBorder.java:80)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getInsets(JComponent.java:1894)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTextUI.java:935)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTextAreaUI.java:121)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1734)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTextArea.getPreferredSize(JTextArea.java:623)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:799)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1541)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1530)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1725)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1660)

and then the infinite loop as above....

Hello Wayne, you know that with the information you give us, we can only give you a pat on the shoulder and wish you luck... and happy new year!!!.

A [mre] would let us understand whether you're doing something that AWT applications should avoid (like overriding validate() and perhaps doing things validate() should not do).  And are you sure you're not using Swing?  I see JTextArea in your stack traces.

Happy New Year! :-) A mini example might take months to make (how to deconstruct the elephant?) — I'd hoped someone would say "Happened to me too!". Very little Swing, and not here. The problem was bypassed by fiddling with pure AWT components. We hadn't overridden validate() before, but we now we did, pushing the call to another thread, which didn't stop the S.O.E. but at least the GUI keeps going. However, note that the validate calls in this stack trace are apparently not in our objects. Perhaps these are parallel containers built with Swing for the peers???

Thanks so much for responding -- this feels very much like a shot in the dark, given how little information I'm giving you about such a complex system.

Rereading what you posted, I see at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338), since it is very rare to find an infinite loop in a GUI, it seems to me a good place to start looking, a loop that works on a Map.

If it would be complex to create an [MRE] there is a good chance that the question is not a good match for this site. You could try reporting the bug to the OpenJDK project.

I very much doubt that there is a bug in HashMap, given the decades of rigorous testing it has undergone.  If there were such a bug, creating a [mre] demonstrating it would be easy.  I think it is more likely that your custom validate() implementation, which can affect when and how other components are validated, is responsible.
